# Browser Details from javascript without using ActiveX controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i am using "window.navigator.userAgent" or "$.browser" then these are asking me to allow to run the ActiveX controls But My application should not use any of ActiveX controls. Can anyone help me to find the solution for this??

Comment: What browser causes `window.navigator.userAgent` property access to generate an ActiveX prompt? That seems *very* unusual.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to know if certain JavaScript commands are available, there's a better way to do that than checking the browser.

Comment: neither of those should cause an ActiveX warning.

Comment: I suspect this warning shows up in IE for *any* script run from a `file:` page, not only for scripts that ask for `userAgent`.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, "ActiveX Controls" is Internet Explorer code for "JavaScript".

Don't load webpages directly from your file system using Internet Explorer. Run them from a web server instead (which can be installed locally).

You are running into a security feature designed to protect your files from malicious, downloaded HTML documents. In principle, it is a good feature, but it has terrible messaging.